# In phonetic writing, what does italics mean?

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries, italics, ipa

The word government is supposed to be pronounced **guhv**-ern-m*uh* nt

See here http://www.dictionary.com/browse/government?s=t

Comment: This appears to be an *ad hoc*, non-standard phonetic spelling system. There is no use of italics in IPA. Anyways, it appears that *uh* is italicized to set it apart as a digraph representing a reduced, unstressed vowel (so you don't think there is an **h** sound in the word).

Comment: That's not IPA, it's just a miscellaneous scheme. It seems to be italicized as a way of distinguishing unstressed /ə/ "*uh*" from stressed /ʌ/ "**uh**."

Comment: @jlovegren Seems like very few dictionaries use true IPA? I checked Merriam Webster to see how the word "father" is pronounced, and it says ˈfä-thər with "th" underscored. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/father I suppose that an underscored "th" is like a voiced "th", or ð in IPA?

Comment: @Gelb: Specifically, few American dictionaries use regular IPA. It's more commonly used in British dictionaries, like the [Oxford online British English dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/father), [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/father?a=british), or [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/father).

Comment: American bilingual dictionaries often use IPA-based phonemic systems for the English side; I used to surprise my undergraduate students regularly by telling them to look at the pronunciations in the English-Spanish part of their bilingual dictionary. American dictionaries for monolingual English speakers don't use IPA or anything scientific, because, like the metric system, it's considered too hard for Americans to understand.

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [spelling pronunciation key](http://www.dictionary.com/pronunciation/Spell_pron_key) for dictionary.com. This tells you what all these strange spellings mean.

Dictionary.com uses a non-standard phonetic respelling. You can also get the IPA (international phonetic alphabet) pronunciation by clicking the IPA/Spell button.

Comment: Sadly, most of the online dictionaries don't offer obvious links to their pronunciation guides.  How did you track down that one?

Comment: @Hot Licks: It took me a few tries with Google.

Comment: Strangely it seems like this website is no longer on the dictionary.com domain. Here is an [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170912190300/http://www.dictionary.com/pronunciation/Spell_pron_key) of it. It seems as though even the last (working) version of the website does not explain what the italics mean.